# Gem for managing state without event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I want to store a state in the model, and one can change from one state to any other state. The list of states are predefined in the model.

A state-machine it too much for me, because I don't need events/transitions between states, and don't want to write N-squared transitions (to allow any state to transfer to any other state).

Is there a good Rails gem for doing this? I want to avoid writing all the constants/accessors/checking validity myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the correct keyword to search for should be ['Active Record Enumeration'](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Enumerations)

I choose the second one called [enumerize](https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize). It provide nice API and good form input generator. It also have a simple scope and accessors.

Answer (score 2):

A gem would be too much for such functionality.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  # validation
  validate :state_is_in_list

  # All the possible states
  STATUS = %w{foo bar zoo loo}

  # method to change to a state. !! Not sure if this is the right syntax
  STATUS.each do |state|
    define_method "#{state}!" do
      write_attribute :state, state
    end

    # Also ? methods are handy for conditions
    define_method "#{state}?" do
      state == read_attribute(:state)
    end
  end
  # So you can do model.bar! and it will change state to 'bar'
  # And model.bar? will return true if it is in 'bar' state


  private
  def child_and_team_code_exists
   errors.add(:state, 'Not a valid state') unless STATUS.include? state
  end

end
```